# Maintaining auto-logins throughout several browsers

Tags: php, cookies, authentication

My site will offer a "Remember me" option, with which a login cookie will be set and their cookie field in the database will be updated. While this works perfectly well for users who use only one browser, problems arise when they use the "remember me" option on several: the second browser overrides the cookie column in the database thus rendering the first cookie unusable. In code this would look similar to this:

**Browser 1, login and remember**

```
$db->setLoginCookie();
setcookie(login cookie);
```

**Browser 1, login with cookie**

```
if (db_has_valid_cookie()) login();
else show_login_form();
```

**Browser 2, login and remember**

```
$db->replaceCookie();
setcookie(new cookie);
```

**Browser 1, attempt to login with cookie**

```
if (db_has_valid_cookie()) login(); //Does not work because it's been overridden
else show_login_form(); //Login form is shown
```

Could anyone please suggest a workaround to this issue?

Comment: do not replace the cookie?

Comment: One solution would be a one-to-many table for login tokens in your database, rather than storing only one per user.

Comment: @YourCommonSense and wouldn't keeping the cookie the same throughout a period of time prove to be a security issue?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski That sounds like a good idea, I'll try it. Thanks!

Comment: But don't different browsers use their own cookies? or do you mean you want multiple instance of the same browser to remember the login? if that's the case then all you need to do is set the cookie (which seems like you are already doing so, but i think you may be confusing the concept of the 'remember me' feature).

Comment: @Zubair1 I am aware how cookies work. My problem is that I am bad at problem descriptions. :) What I am trying to achieve is a scenario where a user logging in from a different browser wouldn't override the cookie value in a database thus invalidating the cookie on their other browser. I'm currently trying out Michael's solution to see how it works. :)

Comment: plus, i don't think you need to save any thing extra in your db to make a remember me feature.. the idea is to save only a cookie (encrypted with maybe a userid).

Comment: @Alorel: i just started to get after going throw your description a few times. But like i said in my last comment you don't need to save anything extra in your db to mark a user as logged in. Basically what you do is save a cookie with the userid (encrypted) and a sessionID, you can then check to see if the user has the cookie and if it does process it to see if its a valid user with a valid session in the db. Nothing else is need. You are probably over-engineering here :)

Comment: @Zubair1 Well if people used your approach then you'd have to re-enter your password every time you open up, say, Facebook. I'm trying to make a persistent login, not a way to handle a user's session. As for storing only an encrypted user ID, this would make the cookie stay the same for each user until they delete their account, I need the cookie to change every so often.

Comment: @Alorel: i just gave you a basic idea, you can do more then just simply encrypt.. you can also hash (which i do).. and i don't understand why anyone would have to re-enter their passwords.. i haven't experienced anything like that nor have received any reports of something similar. AND.. you don't simply validate the user using the userid, you have to make sure its mapped to the sessionid.. last but not least is the fact that this is persistent login. If you are trying keep the login persistent across different browsers then that surely is different, as this would not work with that. I........

Comment: @Alorel: ... I on the other hand won't recommend doing persistent login across multiple (different) browsers, as apart from being complicated, it could expose security issues. But at-least i got what you're looking for now :)

Comment: @Zubair1 Well, perhaps if I saw your code it'd be easier to understand what you mean exactly, because at the moment I'm unable to exactly grasp how I could get your solution to work. :) As for security, I am already giving it **a lot** of attention and I'll see to it that this feature will not become one. :)